# SQL total spent per customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

this is my first time asking a question on here, and I can usually find what I need just from seaching, however this time I'm stuck and I'm hoping someone here can help.

Here's the gist. I have created a database for a hair dressing studio. there are five tables. The only one's this question deals with is the Customers table (stores customer details), the ProductSales table (store details about each product sale, and HairCuts table, store details about each cut.

I need a query that will list the total spent on both hair cuts and products for each customer in the customers table.

I have two separate queries that work fine. Each one calculates the total spent by each customer for EITHER hair cuts or products. I need to somehow combine these into one that will show the total.

```
SELECT c.customer_ID, c.first_Name, c.last_name, 
SUM(hc.cost) AS hc_sales_total
FROM Customers c, HairCuts hc
WHERE c.customer_ID = hc.customer_ID
GROUP BY c.customer_ID;

SELECT c.customer_ID, c.first_Name, c.last_name, 
SUM(ps.cost) AS ps_sales_total
FROM Customers c,ProductSales ps
WHERE c.customer_ID = ps.customer_ID
GROUP BY c.customer_ID;
```

I believe the issues I am havng are stemming from the fact that, while all customers have purchased at least one hair cut, not all have purchased products. Anyway, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`UNION` your two queries together.

Then you'll have a table with all the costs.

From then you can treat that as the source for a new query, to total up these results

```
SELECT customer_ID, first_name, last_name, sum(hc_sales_total) as totalsales
FROM
(
    SELECT c.customer_ID, c.first_Name, c.last_name, 
    SUM(hc.cost) AS hc_sales_total
    FROM Customers c 
         INNER JOIN HairCuts hc
         ON c.customer_ID = hc.customer_ID
    GROUP BY c.customer_ID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.customer_ID, c.first_Name, c.last_name, 
    SUM(ps.cost) AS ps_sales_total
    FROM Customers c
         INNER JOIN ProductSales ps
         ON c.customer_ID = ps.customer_ID
    GROUP BY c.customer_ID
) sales
GROUP BY customer_ID, first_name, last_name
```

Of course, the inner grouping is superfluous, so

```
SELECT customer_ID, first_name, last_name, sum(cost) as totalsales
FROM
(
    SELECT c.customer_ID, c.first_Name, c.last_name, hc.cost
    FROM Customers c 
         INNER JOIN HairCuts hc
         ON c.customer_ID = hc.customer_ID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT c.customer_ID, c.first_Name, c.last_name, ps.cost
    FROM Customers c
         INNER JOIN ProductSales ps
         ON c.customer_ID = ps.customer_ID
) sales
GROUP BY customer_ID, first_name, last_name
```

Comment: You sir, are a genius and I love you forever. Thank you. This works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all three sums, you can do this using a `union all`/`group by` approach:

```
SELECT c.customer_ID, c.first_Name, c.last_Name,
       SUM(hp.hc_sales) as hp.hc_sales_total, SUM(hp.ps_sales) as hp.ps_sales_total,
       SUM(hp.hc_sales_total + hp.ps_sales_total) as Total
FROM ((SELECT hc.customer_ID, hc.cost AS hc_sales, 0 as ps_sales
       FROM HairCuts hc 
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT ps.customer_ID, 0, ps.cost AS ps_sales
       FROM ProductSales ps
      )
     ) hp JOIN
     Customers c
     on c.customer_ID = hp.customer_ID
GROUP BY c.customer_ID, c.first_Name, c.last_Name;
```

Note the ways that this query differs from yours:

1. The two join's have been factored out, so each subquery is working on only one table.
2. The join after the `union all` uses explicit `join` syntax, with the conditions going in the `on` clause.
3. There is only one aggregation.

Comment: Except this is going to give two rows per `customerId`, because you don't have an outer aggregate, but do have two rows from the `UNION ALL`.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse . . . There was another problem as well with the variable names.  But the lack of outer `group by` -- I was thinking of two different ways to solve the problem, and ended up with an incorrect hybrid solution.  It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
SELECT c.customer_ID, c.first_Name, c.last_name, 
SUM( isnull( hc.cost,0) + isnull(ps.cost,0) ) AS hc_pc_sales_total
FROM Customers c, HairCuts hc, ProductSales ps
WHERE c.customer_ID = hc.customer_ID AND
      c.customer_ID = ps.customer_ID
GROUP BY c.customer_ID;
```

I don't know which Database you use, but please do not forget to deal with the 'null' values by using 'ISNULL' or something.

See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp for ISNULL functions.

Comment: It's best to avoid the implicit-join syntax (comma-separated `FROM` clause) in favor of explicitly listing joins.  Anyways, this will **NOT** get the correct answer, assuming more than one of either `ProductSales` or `HairCuts`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an *outer join* to make sure that all customers are represented in the joined table. Here is your second query thus modified:

```
SELECT
    c.customer_ID,
    c.first_Name,
    c.last_name,
    COALESCE(SUM(ps.cost), 0) AS ps_sales_total
FROM
    Customers AS c
    LEFT JOIN ProductSales AS ps ON c.customer_ID = ps.customer_ID
GROUP BY
    c.customer_ID
```

Notice also that I used COALESCE to make sure that the result of the SUM is zero and not NULL.

By the way, I personally do not like the comma-syntax for joining tables (`FROM c, ps`). I prefer to use the explicit syntax (`FROM c JOIN ps ON ...`). In part, this is because I think it is better to put the join logic in the FROM clause rather than combining it with the WHERE clause.

Also, why is it `first_Name` with an `N` but `last_name` with an `n`?

In regards to combining the results of the two queries, there is more than one approach you could take. You could use a union in a subquery and then a SUM with GROUP BY, as suggested by podiluska. Or you could select the result of a subquery for each row in the customers table:

```
SELECT
    (
        SELECT COALESCE(SUM(hc.cost), 0)
        FROM HairCuts AS hc
        WHERE hc.customer_ID = c.customer_ID
    ) + (
        -- similar to above
    ) AS AmountSpent
FROM
    Customers c
```

Comment: Unless you escape object names, SQL (as a language) doesn't care about capitalization, so it doesn't matter (I'm assuming it's a typo from holding `shift` while getting the underscore).  I'd avoid doing the subqueries as part of the `SELECT`, as this will (usually) run the statement for each row, and won't be as performant.  Personally, I'd put the entire subquery in the `COALESCE(...)`, as I feel it makes your intentions clearer (and what's going on more obvious).

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer pre-aggregating into new table-references:

```
SELECT Customers.customer_Id, Customer.first_Name, Customer.last_Name,
       COALESCE(HairCuts.cost, 0) + COALESCE(ProductSales.cost, 0) as totalCost
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN (SELECT customer_Id, SUM(cost) AS cost
           FROM HairCuts
           GROUP BY customer_Id) HairCuts
       ON HairCuts.customer_Id = Customers.customer_Id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT customer_Id, SUM(cost) AS cost
           FROM ProductSales
           GROUP BY customer_Id) ProductSales
       ON ProductSales.customer_Id = Customers.customer_Id
```

(not tested as I have no data to base it against.  Should work in any RDBMS, though)